# sendmessage api to select a specific index of combobox control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi, combobox

I am coding an app that can select another app's `ComboBox` with a certain index.
For example, I want to select the second listed item "Adobe flash player" from my app with hooking.

The `ComboBox` app is not mine so I cannot modify the target app.

Usually, putting a text or clicking a button can be done by using `Sendmessage` API in VB.Net.

The handle value(hWnd) of that `ComboBox` can be retrieved.
I want to know which function(api) to use and which value should be used.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send [`CB_SETCURSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775899(v=vs.85).aspx) message to the combo box. The `wParam` parameter of [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) should be zero-based index of the item which you want to set as selected index and the `lParam` is useless here.

> An application sends a [`CB_SETCURSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775899(v=vs.85).aspx) message to select a string in the
>   list of a combo box. If necessary, the list scrolls the string into
>   view. The text in the edit control of the combo box changes to reflect
>   the new selection, and any previous selection in the list is removed.
>
> - `wParam`: Specifies the zero-based index of the string to select. If this
>     parameter is –1, any current selection in the list is removed and the
>     edit control is cleared.
> - `lParam`: This parameter is not used.

**C# Example**

```cs
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
const int CB_SETCURSEL = 0x014E;
void SetSelectedIndex(IntPtr comboBoxHandle, int index)
{
    SendMessage(comboBoxHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, index, 0);
}
```

**VB.NET Example**

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, _
                            ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function
Const CB_SETCURSEL As Integer = &H14E
Sub SetSelectedIndex(comboBoxHandle As IntPtr, index As Integer)
    SendMessage(comboBoxHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, index, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks. Additionally, is there any method to get the Count of the ComboBox control?

Comment: `CB_GETCOUNT` is for getting items count. Feel free to notify me if you asked a question about it and I'll post an example for you.

Comment: could you please write an example code retrieving Count and, if possible, the content text of the ComboBox? thank you!

Comment: Would you mind to ask a question about it? it would not be suitable for comments :) In case which you want to try it yourself, to get the text of selected item you can use `CB_GETLBTEXT` and `CB_GETLBTEXTLEN` messages. As an option you can create a class which encapsulates the logic of working with a win32 combo box.