# Select value in ComboBox with UI Automation

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, ui-automation

I would like to select a value of a ComboBox with the Help of the Automation API. Unfortunately, the posts I found in StackOverflow didn't work for me.

I tried the following code:

```
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
const int CB_SETCURSEL = 0x014E;

void SetSelectedIndex(IntPtr comboBoxHandle, int index)
{
    SendMessage(comboBoxHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, index, 0);
}
```

However, if I call this method with the Handle of a ComboBox and any index, nothing happens...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267361/sendmessage-api-to-select-a-specific-index-of-combobox-control

Comment: Do you need to automate your own app or are you trying to automate a Control of another Process? In this case, how did you get the Handle of that Control? Does it have a Handle? I.e, if it's, e.g., a WPF app, its Controls don't have handles. You should add some details about this, to clarify the context of the operations. -- In case you actually want to use UI Automaton, You should also post the code you wrote for this.

Comment: I try to to select a handle on another window process. Not in my own program. Ive got the handle of that window and also of that combobox I would like to Select a value on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# wrappers around UIAutomation like [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI) or older [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White).
You can use UIA in C# directly ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/february/test-run-the-microsoft-ui-automation-library), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/obtaining-ui-automation-elements)), but probably end up writing same wrappers around controls/patterns/elements-search and workarounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894386/16297051) by yourself. Writing automation in C++ require strong reasons...